Can't install spaCy (and thinc) on Python
When I try to install spaCy to use with chatterBot (somehow it didn't download with ChatterBot), first I got an error because I did not have the Cython module installed into my virtual environment, and then I got stuck into this:
pip install spacy
Collecting spacy
  Using cached spacy-3.7.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl.metadata (27 kB)
Collecting spacy-legacy<3.1.0,>=3.0.11 (from spacy)
  Using cached spacy_legacy-3.0.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
...

Building wheels for collected packages: thinc
  Building wheel for thinc (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for thinc (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [448 lines of output]
      Cythonizing sources
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc
      ... copying and creating stuff ...
      dependency C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Include\Python.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_hk7kebr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_hk7kebr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayscalars.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_hk7kebr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ndarrayobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_hk7kebr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ndarraytypes.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_hk7kebr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ufuncobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Include\Python.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_hk7kebr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_hk7kebr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\arrayscalars.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_hk7kebr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ndarrayobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_hk7kebr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ndarraytypes.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      dependency C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_hk7kebr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\ufuncobject.h won't be automatically included in the manifest: the path must be relative
      reading manifest file 'thinc.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: manifest_maker: MANIFEST.in, line 4: path 'tmp/' cannot end with '/'

      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.cpp' found under directory 'thinc'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'thinc.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_hk7kebr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:215: _Warning: Package 'thinc.backends' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'thinc.backends' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'thinc.backends' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.

              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

              If you don't want 'thinc.backends' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'thinc.backends' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_hk7kebr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:215: _Warning: Package 'thinc.extra' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'thinc.extra' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'thinc.extra' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.

              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

              If you don't want 'thinc.extra' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'thinc.extra' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_hk7kebr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:215: _Warning: Package 'thinc.layers' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'thinc.layers' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'thinc.layers' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.

              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

              If you don't want 'thinc.layers' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'thinc.layers' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_hk7kebr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:215: _Warning: Package 'thinc.tests.mypy.configs' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'thinc.tests.mypy.configs' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'thinc.tests.mypy.configs' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.

              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

              If you don't want 'thinc.tests.mypy.configs' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'thinc.tests.mypy.configs' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      copying thinc\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc
      copying thinc\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc
      copying thinc\backends\cblas.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\backends
      copying thinc\backends\cpu_kernels.hh -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\backends
      copying thinc\backends\linalg.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\backends
      copying thinc\backends\numpy_ops.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\backends
      copying thinc\extra\search.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\extra
      copying thinc\layers\premap_ids.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\layers
      copying thinc\layers\sparselinear.cpp -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\layers
      copying thinc\backends\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\backends
      copying thinc\backends\_custom_kernels.cu -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\backends
      copying thinc\backends\_murmur3.cu -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\backends
      copying thinc\backends\cblas.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\backends
      copying thinc\backends\cblas.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\backends
      copying thinc\backends\linalg.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\backends
      copying thinc\backends\linalg.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\backends
      copying thinc\backends\numpy_ops.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\backends
      copying thinc\backends\numpy_ops.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\backends
      copying thinc\extra\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\extra
      copying thinc\extra\search.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\extra
      copying thinc\extra\search.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\extra
      copying thinc\layers\premap_ids.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\layers
      copying thinc\layers\sparselinear.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\layers
      copying thinc\extra\tests\c_test_search.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\extra\tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\tests\mypy\configs
      copying thinc\tests\mypy\configs\mypy-default.ini -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\tests\mypy\configs
      copying thinc\tests\mypy\configs\mypy-plugin.ini -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\tests\mypy\configs
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\tests\mypy\outputs
      copying thinc\tests\mypy\outputs\fail-no-plugin.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\tests\mypy\outputs
      copying thinc\tests\mypy\outputs\fail-plugin.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\tests\mypy\outputs
      copying thinc\tests\mypy\outputs\success-no-plugin.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\tests\mypy\outputs
      copying thinc\tests\mypy\outputs\success-plugin.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\thinc\tests\mypy\outputs
      running build_ext
      C:\Users\scrht\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_hk7kebr\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:215: _Warning: Package 'thinc.tests.mypy.outputs' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'thinc.tests.mypy.outputs' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'thinc.tests.mypy.outputs' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.

              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

              If you don't want 'thinc.tests.mypy.outputs' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'thinc.tests.mypy.outputs' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
              combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.

              You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        check.warn(importable)
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for thinc
Failed to build thinc
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (thinc)

python 3.8.0 and pip 24.1.2
I tried to install some old versions of spaCy, but it didn't help me (the problem appears again). I'm trying to install Virtual Studio Tools.

Have you tried creating a clean virtual environment and trying in there? When I create a new Python 3.8 virtual environment, pip install spacy doesn't cause an issue. (Windows 10, Python 3.8, pip 24.0 - I doubt a newer version is the issue)

I'm too getting error
/command/build_py.py:215: _Warning: Package 'thinc.tests.mypy.configs' is absent from the packages configuration.
How did you resolved it?

I'm getting this error too. Any solutions?


pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
pip install --no-cache-dir spacy

The above worked for me on macOS :)

I had the same issue, I had created my virtual environment using
py -m venv venv

I deleted that venv and created a new one using
virutalenv venv

The issue didn't show up in this one and the installation was successful.
